# Lenovo ThinkPad mute LED stopped working

Tags: audio, gentoo, thinkpad, multimedia

I have a ThinkPad X280 running Gentoo. I do some periodic updates, but I don’t reboot very often, and since my last reboot I don’t have the mute LED following the sound state anymore. It can still toggle my mic and speakers, though.

I don’t have the option on alsamixer anymore:
[image: alsamixer]

I don’t know if it’s due to software or firmware update. I use pulseaudio (because firefox and bluetooth).

Here is what could be relevant about it:

```
~ % lspci -k 
[…]
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
[…]
~ % uname -a
Linux alarig 4.19.72-gentoo #3 SMP Tue Oct 29 19:20:49 CET 2019 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
~ % fwupdmgr get-devices
ThinkPad X280 Thunderbolt Controller
  DeviceId:             92b8568ced118a0185f6a06c0cacd0a3e5f059fd
  Guid:                 4808eca4-fd4a-50e6-9e8d-bfd813f063da
  Summary:              Unmatched performance for high-speed I/O
  Plugin:               thunderbolt
  Flags:                internal|updatable|require-ac|supported|registered
  Vendor:               Lenovo
  VendorId:             TBT:0x0109
  Version:              20.00
  Icon:                 computer
  Created:              2019-10-29

LENSE30256GMSP34MEAT3TA
  DeviceId:             e11623b2caa18fee292058a5c09ca4e6152f7ecf
  Guid:                 2e7e091e-c779-5751-b5f9-1ad626f3f123
  Guid:                 0696debf-90a2-5c62-8c96-10857c206b91
  Guid:                 d6a2653a-5464-5b59-bfcb-a05effb8cfe1
  Summary:              NVM Express Solid State Drive
  Plugin:               nvme
  Flags:                internal|updatable|require-ac|registered|needs-reboot
  Vendor:               Lenovo
  VendorId:             NVME:0x17AA
  Version:              1.4.0412
  Icon:                 drive-harddisk
  Created:              2019-10-29

~ % lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    61440  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         102400  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_core           61440  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_pcm                81920  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm
```

I didn’t find a way to echo to a /dev file or whatever to make it work manually.

Thanks!

Comment: test it after booting from a LiveUSB, mayhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to `4.19.82-gentoo` recently and since then it works again. So this is very likely to be a bug in `4.19.72`.